# Open and closed menus icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So here I found a really useful [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JqJce/6/):

I don't have a submenu in another submenu like above, but I've managed the structure. My problem are the icons. When the submenu it's closed, I want an arrow pointing down,

```
.iconOpen{
background-image: url('arrow_accordion_open.png') !important;
width: 11px;
height: 13px;
background-position: center right;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

and when it's opened I want an arrow pointing up.

```
.iconClose{
 width: 11px;
height: 13px;
background-position: center right;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url('arrow_accordion_close.png');
}
```

The thing is i need to do it with background-image or img-scr, because I need a certain arrow. In that jsfiddle they're putting a " + " with "content". But I'm a newbie and I don't know how to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The CSS in the Fiddle is already there. .has-submenu > a:after {
    content:' + ';
}
.has-submenu.nav-open > a:after {
    content:' - ';
}

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding two new classes, you could just amend the `:after` states to do what you want them to.

Ive added your CSS, with a couple of amendments and some new properties and got it to work as you would like. As I don't have the images, it uses a backup of colour to show what happens but removing the colour values and using this where you can access your images will work.

This answer also works for the sub-menu's you have within sub-menu's and doesn't just impact the top level.

```js
$('.has-submenu > a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // slide up currently open except if click is nested within an already open menu
    if ($(this).closest('.nav-open').length === 0)
    {
        $('.nav > .nav-open').removeClass('nav-open').find('> ul > li').slideUp();
    }
    
    // give the <li> the "nav-open" class, then slide the <li> grandchildren
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('nav-open').find('> ul > li').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
a {
    display:block;
    background:#aaa;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    padding:5px;
    color:#fff;
}
li li {
    display:none;
}
.has-submenu > a:after {
    content:'';
    background: url(arrow_accordion_open.png) red;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 11px;
    height: 13px;
    background-position: center right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.has-submenu.nav-open > a:after {
    content:'';
    background: url('arrow_accordion_close.png') blue;
}
li li a {
    padding-left:40px;
    background:#888;
}
li li li a {
    padding-left:80px;
    background:#333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav level-1">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Link</a>
        <ul class="level-2">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Link</a>
        <ul class="level-2">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Link</a>
                <ul class="level-3">
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Link</a>
        <ul class="level-2">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

- [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/etq3fod0/)

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
    a:after {
        content: "" !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: url('arrow_accordion_close.png');
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
remove space between .has-submenu.nav-open 

.has-submenu.nav-open > a:after {
  content:' - ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm still going to post this, since I really don't get why all the given solutions are so incredibly and unnecessarily complex. Like I said, the CSS is already there. You just have to replace the content and remove the space between .has-submenu and .nav-open, since those classes are on the same element.

```
.has-submenu > a:after {
    content:url(arrow_accordion_open.png);
}
.has-submenu.nav-open > a:after {
    content:url(arrow_accordion_close.png);
}
```